# How do I execute code on App Engine without using servlets?

Tags: google-app-engine

My goal is to receive updates for some service (using http request-response) all the time, and when I get a specific information, I want to push it to the users. This code must run all the time (let's say every 5 seconds).

How can I run some code doing this when the server is up (means, not by an http request that initiates the execution of this code) ?

I'm using Java.

Thanks

Comment: create a task that creates another task that'll run in the future when done. Or create a cron style job that runs on a regular schedule. I don't know how to do any of that in Java but it can be done in Python on GAE so I'm sure it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

[Scheduled Tasks With Cron for Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron)

You can set your own schedule (e.g. every minute), and it will call a specified handler for you.

You may also want to look at

[App Engine Modules in Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/)

before you implement your code. You may separate your user-facing and backend code into different modules with different scaling options.

UPDATE:

A great comment from @tx802:

I think 1 minute is the highest frequency you can achieve on App Engine, but you can use cron to put 12 tasks on a Push Queue, either with delays of 5s, 10s, ... 55s using TaskOptions.countdownMillis() or with a processing rate of 1/5 sec.

Comment: I think 1 minute is the highest frequency you can achieve on App Engine, but you can use cron to put 12 tasks on a Push Queue, either with delays of 5s, 10s, ... 55s using [TaskOptions.countdownMillis()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions#countdownMillis(long)) or with a processing rate of 1/5 sec.